# Jenkins JUnit Test Result Report plugin states that the JUnit xml file is not found?

Tags: ant, junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The exact message received from jenkins is:

```
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
```

When configuring the JUnit Test Result Report plugin, on entering the 'Test Report XMLs' path as '/reports/TEST-*.xml', the following error is displayed beneath the path:

```
'/reports/TEST-*.xml' doesn't match anything: '' exists but not '/reports/TEST-*.xml'
```

I have tried using the full path as well but that produces the same result. In both cases the paths should have picked up the 'TESTS-TestSuites.xml' file that was present in the /reports directory.

I'm not sure whether this is a problem with the plugin or the XML file being generated. I'm also aware that it could be an issue with the ant build script that I have written to run the JUnit tests and produce the XML result file therefore I have included the contents of this below in case something needs to be changed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="jenkins-tests" basedir="." default="linux">

<property name="junit.output.dir" value="output"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="libs" />
<property name="bin.dir" value="bin" />
<property name="full-compile" value="true" />

<path id="classpath.base"/>

<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="${bin.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${src.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit.jar" />
    <path refid="classpath.base" />
</path>

<target name="clean" description="Clean up build artefacts">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/${junit.output.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" depends="clean" description="Prepare for build">
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${junit.output.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}/reports"/> 
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" verbose="${full-compile}" includeAntRuntime="false" >
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="true" haltonfailure="false">
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="true"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>

<target name="test-reports" depends="test">
    <junitreport tofile="TESTS-TestSuites.xml" todir="${junit.output.dir}/reports">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}/reports" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
</project>
```

I've been researching into this problem for a while now and haven't found any solution so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the tests at least once?  This error does appear when configuring the plugin for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, the tests run fine and say the build is successful. It's only trying to generate the reports with the plugin that cause the build to fail.

Comment: @ Ben : Could you browse to the TEST*xml files via jenkins->job->workspace->... ? It will give an idea what pattern is really needed. Shiva Kumar's answer should have worked.

Comment: @Jayan I had a look in the job's workspace. It's strange as on my local server the path is \Clients\website\versions\ben\includes\fuel\app\tests\selenium\JenkinsTests\outp‌​ut\reports whereas in the replicated path under jenkins/job/workspace in includes/fuel/app the tests directory and those directories within it are not there. Do you know why?

Comment: @ Ben :  jenkins has default workspace , managed by itself.  It also allows you to provide a custom workspace (hidden under advanced setting of job)

Comment: @ Jayan : Output I now have is... test-reports:
[junitreport] Processing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins-tests/workspace/includes/fuel/app/tests/selenium/JenkinsTests/output/reports/TESTS-TestSuites.xml to /tmp/null727956119
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] Transform time: 578ms
[junitreport] Deleting: /tmp/null727956119

1/2

Comment: BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
Recording test results
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 20):

Jenkins looks for the path from the workspace root. Ensure that the given path is correct or  use wildcards to look in multiple locations. Try using `**/reports/TEST-*.xml`
Are you sure the reports folder is right under the workspace? Verify manually if the test result files are indeed present in the location given in the path.

Comment: I've used that path and it has gotten rid of the initial path error but I still get the xml not found error when running the job. Maybe the reports folder is in the wrong place. Currently Jenkins runs on a separate server to the tests. Would the reports folder have to be on the Jenkins server and the reports in the ant script pointed to there?

Comment: On the local server (not the jenkins server) I have the base directory that contains the src, bin and libs directories for my JUnit tests as well as the ant build xml file. The build.xml file makes the output directory (${junit.output.dir}) alongside these other directories when it runs and then the reports directory is made within there. The jenkins directories are completely separate on their own server. I just looked on the jenkins server and I have the following path to the job's workspace: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jUnit Test/workspace
Should the reports, test and build.xml be here instead?

Comment: \Clients\website\versions\ben\includes\fuel\app\tests\selenium\JenkinsTests\output\reports

Comment: This does not look like it is in the place where the job is run. Can you check by giving full path \Clients\website\versions\ben\includes\fuel\app\tests\selenium\JenkinsTests\outp‌​ut\reports\TEST-*.xml and check in the JUnit  Report plugin? And can you tell if your src, bine and lib directories are coming from SVN or they exist in hardcoded path in the local server?

Comment: The full path produces the same errors and the src, bin and libs directories exist are in a hardcoded path in the local server.

Answer (score 8):

For my **Android** project which has multiple Gradle product flavors I used the following path for `Test report XMLs`:

```
**/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml
```

[image: JUnit plugin]

Comment: That path helped me out, thanks. It works, however, only with JUnit4. 
I keep trying over and over again with JUnit5, using different paths, without success.  Do you know any other path that might work with JUnit5 also? Or any other workaround... It would be appreciated ;)

Comment: @arthur0304 I haven't looked into grabbing JUnit5 test results. Therefore, I strongly suggest that you post your issue as a separate question on Stackoverflow so it gets much more attention than your comment here.