# Jenkins Error: No test report files were found. Configuration error?

Tags: windows, jenkins, junit, ant

I can't figure out why I have this error. I've installed ant via jenkins on windows.

My project is called *test-freestyle* and is held at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test-freestyle

I've manually created an empty **Reports** folder inside that test-freestyle folder and am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_unit_testing.htm) and [this StackOverflow post to troubleshoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933375/jenkins-junit-test-result-report-plugin-states-that-the-junit-xml-file-is-not-fo).

Here is the folder structure, proof that jenkins sees the directory [build failure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuM0t.png)
[image: build failure image]
Is it becasue Program Files needs admin rights to create files?

My code is in the JUnitTest1 project. My test cases are in *JUnitTest1UnitTests*

```
build-project:
    [echo] JUnitTest1: C:\Users\----\Documents\workspace\JUnitTest1\build.xml

init:

build-project:
    [echo] JUnitTest1UnitTests: C:\Users\-----\Documents\workspace\JUnitTest1UnitTests\build.xml

build:

 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 0 seconds
 Recording test results
 ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: every job will have a workspace. Your image says no files are under that. Could you search and find where did they go?

Comment: Did you find solution? same issue I have.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Go to you job then click Configure, then open Advance option and look for "use custom workspace" set it as your need and adjust the postbuild action to use folders relatives to your "new" workspace path