# Jenkins - failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

I'm beginner for "Jenkins" and following [this tutorial](http://mmorejon.github.io/en/blog/continuous-integration-jenkins-ios9-xcode/).

At the [Sixth step](http://mmorejon.github.io/en/blog/continuous-integration-jenkins-ios9-xcode/#step-six--configure-junit-plugin) I got below error.

> xcodebuild: error: Scheme JenkinsTest is not currently configured for the test action.
>
> Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
>   Recording test results
>   ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
>   Finished: FAILURE

In the **Test report XMLs** I did set **"test-reports/.*xml"**

I tried to find my solution and also many questions are founded on SO [like same issue I have too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060527/jenkins-error-no-test-report-files-were-found-configuration-error) but did not get solution.

I have some confusion, Is .xml file automatically generated by "Jenkins" or First we manually need to add .xml file ?

In short guide me on right direction based on above error.

Comment: Does the `test-reports` directory exist (in Jenkins workspace)? I can not test in the moment, but I _think_ it has another name on our system.

Comment: @shallowThought - Yes its exist.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Did you find the solution, Coz I am having the same issue? Do we need to create `.xml` file manually or let Jenkins create it.

Comment: For the 'not configured for the test action' error, see this other question. without the project being properly configured for testing, you will not end up with a results file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481630/xcode-project-scheme-is-not-currently-configured-for-the-test-action

Answer (score 43):

You can also enable the 'allowEmptyResults' option so that the junit plugin won't throw an exception when it doesn't find test results.

This way it doesn't matter if the 'test-results' directory exists.

```
junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: '**/test-results/*.xml'
```

Answer (score 18):

First make sure junit.xml is getting generated after the test run.

Jenkins job at times cannot see past the current workspace. so it is always a good idea to copy the reports back to the current workspace before using it.

```
    cd <path to report>
    cp *.xml $WORKSPACE
```

Now the jenkins should pick-up the report.
Note: The config may show error first(since it cannot find the xml file in workspace) but after a build this should go away and also the result should get recorded

Comment: I am on aws linux instance # junit
MobaXterm X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:11.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: I was having the same issue and copying the xml file to the root of the workspace resolved it for me. I had been running "junit <path-to-file>" instead, which wasn't working.

I do not understand why this fixes it, however.

Can you explain this statement more:
"Jenkins job at times cannot see past the current workspace. so it is always a good idea to copy the reports back to the current workspace before using it."

Answer (score 10):

I'm using nosetest (python) to generate an xUnit compatible file and I was getting:

```
ERROR: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

I was using junit plugin as:

```
junit "test-results-unit.xml"
```

`junit` seems to add `WORKSPACE` directory by default so using the full `PATH` to the file wouldn't work either. I created symlink from the resulting file to the WORKSPACE directory to make it work:

```
  sh 'ln -s tests/test-results-unit.xml $WORKSPACE'
  junit "test-results-unit.xml"
```

Comment: I am also getting same error, tried the approach suggested by you but no luck. Could you please advise if any other changes I need to make

Comment: @GauravParek try finding the `test-results-unit.xml` file first by running `ls` or `find`, then create the symlink to the correct path

Answer (score 5):

Other answers suggest copying the files to the workspace directory, but for me simply changing the path to start with '**' seemed to solve the issue

```
junit '**/test-reports/*.xml'
```

The [Jenkins junit plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit) says that you need to "specify the path to JUnit XML files in the Ant glob syntax". I've not dug into the full details of what this means, but starting the path with '**' was enough to get it working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Acid, it really helped me.
First, copy the module/build/test-results to workspace directory

```
cp -r app/build/test-results $WORKSPACE/test-results
```

And then I used this wildcard path

```
**/test-results/**/*.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: "${WORKSPACE}/test-results/*.xml"
```

or just:

```
junit "${WORKSPACE}/test-results/*.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am scanning checkov and doing below worked for me:

```
                sh 'checkov -f tfplan.json --framework terraform_plan --soft-fail -o cli -o junitxml --output-file-path results.xml'
                            junit skipPublishingChecks: true, testResults: '**/*.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my test report file name got changed due to an upgrade in `scala` version,

Hence I have to change from,

```
junit '/myworkspace/target/myreport.xml'
```

to

```
junit '/myworkspace/target/TEST-myreport.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the path where your test reports are saved in your .jenkins workspace:

```
/Users/<USERNAME/>/.jenkins/workspace/<PROJECT/>/target/surefire-reports/*.xml
```

to find the folder type in your terminal:

```
.jenkins
```

then

```
open .
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and find that i have used jococo instead of jacoco in my Jenkins file.

```
post{
              always{
                junit 'target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                jacoco execPattern: 'target/jacoco.exec'
                
              }
            }
```